# Hello everyone I am a beginner in programming and I have a problem in my project

Tags: java

here if I want the value of the if statement it gives me 0.0 not what I want how can I solve this problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJqNT.png)

Comment: Please read before posting queation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: An obvious issue here is that you are doing `mark.equals("something")`, but `mark` is a `String[]`: an array of strings will never be equal to a string.

Comment: please don't use SC, copy your code in here instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. And of course. use a meaningful question title. Everybody who comes here has a problem. Be . more specific please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Comment: @kobaltoloy Even I am not really sure what you meant with that comment. The OP probably assumes that he "copied" his code. He gave us a screenshot. So: when you take the time to tell a new user about a problem with his content: then be specific. Dont use abbreviations like "SC" for example.

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet, in method **setMark()** you have taken input from user in array of Strings while in **getPoints()** method you are comparing array of Strings to String. That is why your if() block is always returning false. Example: the result below will always be false.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
         String[] mark = new String[5];

         if(mark.equals("A+")){
             System.out.print("true");
         }
         else{
             System.out.print("false");
         }
    }
```

So in **getPoints()** if you want to calculate total points, you have to iterate through mark[] and then check the grades like "A+" with each array element. Like this :

```
 public double  getPoints(){
        for(String s : mark){
            if(s.equals("A+") || s.equals("a+")){
                point+=5;
            }
            else if(s.equals("B+") || s.equals("b+")){
                point+=4.75;
            }
            //following remaining conditions
        }
    }
```